# Access global field content

Tags: templating, matrix, globals

What could be the reason for this error when I’m targeting a global field?:

`Impossible to access an attribute ("footer") on a boolean variable ("").`

I created a global set *Footer* with a matrix field also named *Footer*, I'm trying to get its content via:

```
{% for block in footer.footer %}
  {% if block.type == "column" %}
    <div>
      <h4>{{ block.headline }}</h4>
      <div>{{ block.columnContent }}</div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: We need more of your code in order to help you.  How do you fetch the global set, what are you doing with it after your loop

Comment: @RobinSchambach Thanks for the advice, I added some lines. Do that help?

Comment: Your code is actually correct. I created the set `footer` with the matrix field `footer` and the block `column` with the fields `headline` and `columnContent` and copied your code as it is with `{% set footer = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('footer')%}` and it works. You error must be related to your fields/your field handles or the field types. Since we don't know your layout we can't really help you

Comment: Could you show us how you fetch your global set? Because of your error message I get the feeling you didn't fetch the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found this shame fault. I created a variable named footer to control the layout – that's not that good in combination with a field named footer.

Sorry for stealing your time...

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything obviously wrong with your code, but something that has caught me out many times is a misspelling of field names, so be sure your twig code matches your field names exactly. One thing that is a bit odd is the error message references "footerContent", but that does not appear in your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. that's because I've tested changing the field handle to ensure that's the right name.. (I've corrected it)

Comment: I just put your code on a test page and it seems to work fine.